# Increase maximum number of connections on DB2 database

Tags: database, windows, db2

How do you increase the maximum number of concurrent connections on a DB2 database running on Windows? Are there any other considerations such as increasing the maximum number of locks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Configuration Parameters Summary](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0005181.html) in the db2 documentation.

There are two levels of configuration: those that apply to every database (the top list, Database Manger Config), and those that are database specific (the bottom list).

At the database manager level you'll want to increase [max_connections](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0003289.html).

At the database level you'll want to increase [max_appls](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000279.html#r0000279).

You won't need to increase any lock parameter but you may need to look at increase things like applheapsz and appl_memory if those start to run low.

Hope this helps.